# PHP layout (template) page

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc-4, layout, codeigniter-2

I am new to PHP, lately I was working mostly with .NET MVC 4.
In MVC you can make a **layout** very easily, end every view knows to use it **without telling each view seperatly.**

**I am trying to figure out what is the best equivalent in PHP.**
I have not found a satisfactory answer yet. The best on was to create a 'header.php', 
and for each view add a **require/include.**
I think this breaks DRY, because on each view i need to specify the header. What if I decide to change the file??
Does anyone has a better suggestion?
I am using codeigniter also.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

As you are using CodeIgniter, there is absolutely no single reason to touch require/include commands.

You can load your header views either from the controller or from the main view. If you are worried about file name changes, create a new config file, add it to `autoload.php` and import your filenames via `$this->config->item('config_var_name')`